# Attempted to read or write protected memory. - After converting app from VS 2005 to VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll

I have an application that was written in VS 2005 (C#).  Works fine, it calls a 3rd Party dll.  Now that I've converted it to VS 2008 (using the wizard), I get the following error when trying to instantiate the 3rd party dll.

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Not sure where to even start debugging this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: As a side note it does the exact same thing under VS 2010.

EDIT: Both VS 2005 and VS 2008 projects using the same code target .NET 2.0 Framework

EDIt: It's an ActiveX library called LPDFCTRLLib.  I've simply added it under References and create a new instance of it:

```
public LPDFCTRLLib.LPDFWndClass olpdf = null;
//and later in my code
//...
//this is where it fails
olpdf = new LPDFCTRLLib.LPDFWndClass();
```

EDIT: Stack Trace

```
at pcl2pdf.Form1.convertPCL(String inputFile, String outputFile) in C:\junk\pcl2pdf\pcl2pdf\pcl2pdf\Form1.cs:line 29
   at pcl2pdf.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\junk\pcl2pdf\pcl2pdf\pcl2pdf\Form1.cs:line 24
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at pcl2pdf.Program.Main() in C:\junk\pcl2pdf\pcl2pdf\pcl2pdf\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: And ConvertPCl is in the DLL?  Any import/Interop decalarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rempve the DLL and then re-Add it. Especially for an unmanaged DLL. And check with the supplier if it is compatible.

And please note: You do not convert Projects to a VS version, except maybe for the config file. You make it target a Framework version. Your question lacks all info about Fx versions.

Comment: Both VS 2005 and VS 2008 projects using the same code target .NET 2.0 Framework

Comment: It's an ActiveX library called LPDFCTRLLib.  I've simply added it under References and create a new instance of it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same problem described: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2009/06/08/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-in-a-net-application.aspx

> "Anyway, the solution was to enable
>   JIT optimization. In other words, in
>   Visual Studio 2008 choose “Tools” and
>   then “Options”. Select “Debugging” and
>   “General” and find the line that says
>   “Suppress JIT optimization on module
>   load”. This kind of makes sure that
>   the debugger and the JIT compiled code
>   aren’t running out of sync because the
>   JIT compiler is such a super duper
>   optimizer of your code. This did the
>   trick."

Comment: This didn't do it...Posted Stack Trace